# Give permission for other user to git update remote?

Tags: linux, git, permissions

I have git clone repo on my home/myuser directory. I want to give another user permission to be able to update it. That user does not have sudo rights.

git repo is in this directory: `/home/myuser/gitrepo/`

When another user goes to that directory and tries to update it with:

`/home/myuser/gitrepo/ git remote update`

It gets this error:
`error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied`

How could I give that user access to only update that repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and protect your repo with a group which has only two members: you and the other user.
See "[How do I share a Git repository with multiple users on a machine?](https://serverfault.com/a/27040/783)"

```
chgrp -R <whatever group> gitrepo
chmod -R g+swX gitrepo
umask 002
```

The other option is to make sure your system umask is repected, with

```
git init --shared=group
# Or, for an existing repo
git config core.sharedRepository true
```

The best practice remains to delegate the authorization to a third-party framework like [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html), based on the authentication of a ssh daemon or an http server.